# Does anyone know the definition for Hochschild cohomology of a differential graded algebra?

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, hochschild-cohomology

Let $A$ with $d$ be a differential graded associative algebra ($DG$ algebra).

What is the definition of the Hochschild complex $C^*(A,A)$?

There should be a Hoshschild differential and a cup product, but I can't find the reference that specifies the formula.  Does any one know?

Comment: A formula appears here http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0211229v1.pdf, probably a repeat question...


Comment: Or try this one: 
http://www.math.sciences.univnantes.fr/~hossein/Publications/Abbaspour-Hoch-IRMA-13-03-2012.pdf, page 4, since you also wanted a formula for cup product. Sign conventions often differ and it's important to have ones which are consistent. 

Comment: http://ctg.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/ctg/files/shared/Zhou/BVTensor110306.pdf mentions them

Comment: @DanielPomerleano Would you be able to fix the dead link in the second comment? Thanks.